# Expo push notification using firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo, react-native-firebase

I want to send notifications using cloud functions in firebase in my react native project. In my free firebase plan, it can't send notifications. If anyone knows, what is the cost per notification ???

Comment: "In my free firebase plan, it can't send notifications" Why not? What is keeping you from doing that? To increase the chance that someone can help, edit your question to include the minimal steps that reproduce where you got stuck, and any relevant error messages you may be getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free Firebase Spark plan doesn't allow outbound networking so you can't reach the expo service from a cloud function.
The costs for the Blaze Plan are $0.12/GB of messages you send. All other products will still cost you nothing, as long as you stay inside the free limits.